# Showing form errors only when clicking submit button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react component that renders a simple log in funcionality, error validation is in a document apart, and while writing if there is an error it will render, but i want them to render only when i click the submit button, i've been the entire day here and still cannot find the solution >.< first time using this platform tho

if possible dont bring me the exact solution but enlighten my mind i'd like to see if i can make it myself

```
import { useState } from "react"
import validations from "./validations"

function Form({login}) {
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    })

    const handlechange = (event)=>{
        setUserData({
            ...userData,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })

        setErrors(validations({
            ...userData,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }))
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()
        login(userData)
    }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="pmail">Email:</label>
            <input 
                type="email" 
                name='email'
                input ={userData.email}
                onChange={handlechange}
            />

            {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}

        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input 
                type="password"
                name="password" 
                input={userData.password}
                onChange={handlechange}
            />

            {errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}
            
        <button>Log In</button>

    </form>
  )
}
export default Form
```

Comment: Dont call `setErrors(validations(...))` in your `handlechange()` but only in your `handleSubmit()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `error` every time in `handlechange()` so the errors are rendered as the state has changed. If you only validate `onSubmit` and set the errors there they will only be rendered when you actually submit the form.

Here a sample implementation based on your code. Try to login with `evil@hacker.com` and any password to see errors getting rendered when you submit the form.

```js
function validations(user) {
    if (user.email.toLowerCase() === "evil@hacker.com") {
        return { email: "Hackers are not allowed here!" }
    }
    return {};
}

function login(user) {
    console.log(`Successfully logged in user ${user.email}`);
}

function isEmpty(obj) {
    for (let i in obj) return false;
    return true;
}

function Form() {
    const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({})
    const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    })

    const handlechange = (event) => {
        setUserData({
            ...userData,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const validationResult = validations(userData);
        if (isEmpty(validationResult)) {
            // no errors
            setErrors({})
            login(userData);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Access denied for ${userData.email}`);
            setErrors(validationResult);
        }

    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} class="form">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
            <input
                type="email"
                name='email'
                input={userData.email}
                onChange={handlechange}
            />

            {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}

            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                input={userData.password}
                onChange={handlechange}
            />

            {errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}

            <button>Log In</button>

        </form>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```